# FIDO2 conformance tool TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, authenticator, webauthn, fido

I'm trying to develop a fido2 iOS BLE authenticator. As of now, Can able to advertise and pair my authenticator with webauthn client. After the client verifies my advertisement data it is writting 'authenticatorGetInfo(83000104)' request to 'controlPoint' characteristic.

As per the fido spec sending the below response to authenticatorGetInfo,

**without cbor**

{
   3 = "EF6CF220-7066-4808-AA22-345C7888BC3F";
   1 =     ( "FIDO_2_0");
}

**with cbor encoding**

[162, 1, 129, 104, 70, 73, 68, 79, 95, 50, 95, 48, 3, 120, 36, 69, 70, 54, 67, 70, 50, 50, 48, 45, 55, 48, 54, 54, 45, 52, 56, 48, 56, 45, 65, 65, 50, 50, 45, 51, 52, 53, 67, 55, 56, 56, 56, 66, 67, 51, 70]

After sending the response, received the following error thrown by Fido2 conformance tool. My question is, Is there any problem in CBOR encoding? or what am i doing wrong here?

```
Authr-Generic-1 Generic FIDO protocol tests
P-1 Send a valid CTAP2 GetInfo request, wait for the response and check that: (a) CTAP2 responseCode is CTAP1_ERR_SUCCESS(0x00) (b) Check that version(0x01) field is presented and is set to "FIDO_2_0" (c) Check that aaguid(0x03) field is presented and is 16 bytes long (d) If GetInfo contains extensions(0x03) field, check that its of type SEQUENCE, and only contains STRINGS (e) If GetInfo contains options(0x04) field, check that its of type MAP (f) If GetInfo contains maxMsgSize(0x05) field, check that its of type NUMBER (g) If GetInfo contains pinProtocols(0x06) field, check that its of type SEQUENCE, and only contains NUMBERS
‣

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at r.it (eval at compileCode (js/sandbox.js:25:26), <anonymous>:3465:58)
    at e (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39758)
    at s.run (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39694)
    at h.runTest (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:45264)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:46126
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44576)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44645
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44051)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44463
    at c (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:1064)
P-2 If GetInfo contains Options field: Check that every option in options is of type Boolean. Additionally: (a) If "up" is set to true, check that metadata.userVerificationDetails contains VerificationMethodDescriptor that has "userVerification" set to USER_VERIFY_PRESENCE (b) If "uv" is set to true, check that metadata.userVerificationDetails contains VerificationMethodDescriptor that has "userVerification" set to either of USER_VERIFY_PASSCODE/FINGERPRINT/VOICEPRINT/FACEPRINT/EYEPRINT/HANDPRINT/PATTERN (c) If "uv" and "up" is false, check that metadata.userVerificationDetails contains VerificationMethodDescriptor that has "userVerification" set to either of USER_VERIFY_NONE
‣ 

TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
    at r.it (eval at compileCode (js/sandbox.js:25:26), <anonymous>:3501:55)
    at e (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39758)
    at s.run (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39694)
    at h.runTest (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:45264)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:46126
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44576)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44645
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44051)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44463
    at c (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:1064)
P-3 If GetInfo contains PinProtocols, and it is not empty, check that Metadata.userVerificationDetails contains VerificationMethodDescriptor set to USER_VERIFY_PASSCODE
‣

TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined
    at r.it (eval at compileCode (js/sandbox.js:25:26), <anonymous>:3537:60)
    at e (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39758)
    at s.run (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:39694)
    at h.runTest (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:45264)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:46126
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44576)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44645
    at r (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44051)
    at file:///Applications/fido-conformance-tools-electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:44463
    at c (js/vendor/mocha.min.js:1:1064) .
```

Comment: Would you mind taking the time to nicely format your question?

Comment: you should post CBOR response in hex string do that I can check

Comment: @Codo thanks for the suggestion. It's formatted now.

Comment: The hex version of CBOR is `a20181684649444f5f325f3003782445463643463232302d373036362d343830382d414132322d333435433738383842433346` and it decodes fine, e.g. on http://cbor.me/.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM For what is worth, if you think there's a possible issue with the FIDO2 conformance tools you could open an issue in https://github.com/fido-alliance/conformance-tools-issues/issues.

Comment: @Codo how do you converted cbor to hex? is there any online tool available to verify?

Comment: @grzuy thanks for sharing. Will post the issue there also.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM I've converted it using some Javascript that I've run in the console tab of the browser's inspector: `[162, 1, 129, ..., 67, 51, 70].reduce((a,c)=>a+('0'+c.toString(16)).substr(-2), '');`

Comment: regarding fido2 response, do I have to add status(0x0) in front of response? like this [0,162, 1, 129, 104, 70, 73, 68, 79, 95, 50, 95, 48, 3, 120, 36, 69, 70, 54, 67, 70, 50, 50, 48, 45, 55, 48, 54, 54, 45, 52, 56, 48, 56, 45, 65, 65, 50, 50, 45, 51, 52, 53, 67, 55, 56, 56, 56, 66, 67, 51, 70]

Comment: @BaoHoa is the posted cbor response correct?

Comment: try this: A60181684649444F5F325F300280035079D699DF01914B10B9035467E7CE823104A562726BF4627570F5627576F464706C6174F469636C69656E7450696EF4051904000680